# Functions: how to use elements of one function in another

Tags: c, global-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int m,n,i,j,k,imp_sum, par_sum,temp,a[100][100];

void calc_rand()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Number of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    int a[m][n];
    for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=(rand()%25)-5;
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void calc_num()
{
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        par_sum=0;
        imp_sum=0;
        for(j=0; j<m; j+=2)
        {
            if (a[j][i]<0)
            {
                par_sum=par_sum+abs(a[j][i]);
            }

        }
        printf("\nSum of emelents <0 %d on even position: %d",i+1, par_sum);
        for(j=1; j<m; j+=2)
        {
            if(a[j][i]>0)
            {
                imp_sum=imp_sum+a[j][i];
            }
        }
        printf("\nSum of elements >0 %d on odd position: %d",i+1, imp_sum);
    }

}

int main()
{
    calc_rand();
    calc_num();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to using functions and I've encountered a problem. When trying to figure out the sum of the elements I need above (I do that in the second function named `calc_num`) it always returns me 0, and I don't really understand why that happens.

Comment: Don't use so many global variables — they make life harder.  Pass parameters.  Use local variables.  Aim for zero globals.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah, but i'll still need those variables later, as m,n for example

Comment: Pass pointers to `int` to the function if you need to get the value back to the calling function: `void calc_rand(int *pm, int *pn) { ...; *pm = m; *pn = n; … }`.  Or do the input separately from the code that uses the sizes, and pass the separately entered sizes to the function that populates the array with random numbers.  Consider separating the printing from the initialization, too — two functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your help, i'm just learning functions for now, i still have a little bit till i'll start learning pointers.

Comment: Consider moving the input code `printf("Number of rows and columns:"); scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);` into `main()`, along with the definitions of `m` and `n`. You should move your declaration of `a` into `main()` too — `int a[m][n];` after you get (and validate) the values for `m` and `n`. Then call `calc_rand(m, n, a);` and `calc_num(m, n, a);`, and change the function definitions to `void calc_rand(int m, int n, int a[m][n]) { … }` and similarly for `calc_num()`.  Variables `i` and `j` should be local variables in both functions.  Create `void print_array(int m, int n, int a[m][n])` for printing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanky you, again, but my problem got solved. I will surely consider your advice in my future work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `calc_rand`, you're creating a *new* array called `a` locally which masks the global variable `a`.  This results in the local `a` being updated instead of the global `a`.

Remove the `int a[m][n];` declaration inside `calc_rand` and it will update the global array.

Comment: Oh damn, thank you! I was too blind to understand my own code myself xd.